# Select from MultiIndex Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have read the other posts on selecting from multiindex columns and it does not help with my scenario.

I have sample columns like this:

```
 ('', 'X', 'Name'),
 ('', 'Y', 'Name'),
 ('S1', 'X', 'OVERALL TOTALS OF ALL SUBJECTS'),
 ('S1', 'X', 'OVERALL PERCENTAGES OF ALL SUBJECTS'),
 ('S2', 'Y', 'OVERALL TOTALS OF ALL SUBJECTS'),
 ('S2', 'Y', 'OVERALL PERCENTAGES OF ALL SUBJECTS')
```

1. I want to rename the "Name" in  ('', 'Y', 'Name') to "Name2".
2. I want to convert all values in column ('', 'X', 'Name') to title case.

I tried using `df.get_level_values(2)` and `df.set_levels(newlist, level=2)` to attempt to change the names of the column using a new list of values but I got the error "Level values must be unique". I also tried `df.rename(columns={('', 'Y', 'Name'): ('', 'Y', 'Name2')}, inplace=True)` but nothing happens. `df.rename(columns={'Name': 'Name2'}, level=2, inplace=True)` renames both "Name" so this does not work as well.

When I try `df[[('', 'X', 'Name')]].str.lower()`, I get error "'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'". Not sure why this is the case. This column ('', 'Y', 'Name') is all names so is string. Also, `df[[('', 'Y', 'Name')]].dtypes` returns "object". I suspect the error is again due to how I am selecting the column.

I have multiple files to read from so the column names might be different for each file. None of the levels have names that are unique. However, the combination of all 3 levels will always be unique.

I need to work on a very specific column in level 2. So, I would like a means to reliably select one such column using something like df[('A', 'B', 'C')] to rename the column as well as to convert its row values to lower case. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to re-create the MultiIndex, something like this:

```
# create the dataframe
cols = [('', 'X', 'Name'),
    ('', 'Y', 'Name'),
    ('S1', 'X', 'OVERALL TOTALS OF ALL SUBJECTS'),
    ('S1', 'X', 'OVERALL PERCENTAGES OF ALL SUBJECTS'),
    ('S2', 'Y', 'OVERALL TOTALS OF ALL SUBJECTS'),
    ('S2', 'Y', 'OVERALL PERCENTAGES OF ALL SUBJECTS')]
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.choice(['FOO', 'BAR', 'BAZ'], (3, len(cols))),
    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(cols))

# 1. Rename the column
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
    x if x != ('', 'Y', 'Name') else ('', 'Y', 'Name2')
    for x in df.columns])

# 2. Set value
df['', 'X', 'Name'] = df['', 'X', 'Name'].str.title()

# Print (transposed for readability)
df.T
```

Output:

```
                                            0    1    2
   X Name                                 Bar  Foo  Baz
   Y Name2                                BAR  BAR  BAZ
S1 X OVERALL TOTALS OF ALL SUBJECTS       BAR  FOO  BAZ
     OVERALL PERCENTAGES OF ALL SUBJECTS  BAZ  BAR  BAR
S2 Y OVERALL TOTALS OF ALL SUBJECTS       BAZ  BAZ  FOO
     OVERALL PERCENTAGES OF ALL SUBJECTS  BAZ  BAZ  FOO
```